# OneNote Android Cache

Tags: cache, microsoft-onenote

I have broken my touch screen on my Google Nexus 7.  I have one weeks work in OneNote on the tablet. It has not been online all this time so is not synced into Onedrive.  I have connected the tablet to my computer using a cable, and I can see the files on the tablet. I want to copy the cached OneNote file on to my PC using windows explorer.  I have searched the Android file system but cannot locate any OneNote files.
Does anyone know if the OneNote cache is accessible in Windows Explorer and if there is someway to recover the notes I have put into OneNote?
Regards
Muz

Answer (score 2):

For security and reliability reasons, private app data are stored in a directory that's only accessible by that app, unless you've previously rooted the device. The only data visible from an MTP connection are files that apps have chosen to share in this way by putting them in the "shared storage".

As well as stopping an attacker from circumventing the screen lock by doing exactly what you're doing, it also stops users breaking apps by messing about with their data files.